# what is the difference of DFS and Backtracking

Tags: depth-first-search, backtracking

i am confused about the difference of DFS and Backtracking algorithm.
in my opinion, Backtracking is just a special version DFS, is it right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The backtracking algorithm** traverses the search tree recursively, from the root down, **in depth-first order**. At each node c, the algorithm **checks whether c can be completed to a valid solution**. **If it cannot, the whole sub-tree rooted at c is skipped** (pruned). Otherwise, the algorithm checks whether c itself is a valid solution, and if so reports it to the user; and recursively enumerates all sub-trees of c. The two tests and the children of each node are defined by user-given procedures.

**Depth-first search (DFS)** starts at the root (selecting some arbitrary node as the root in the case of a graph) and **explores as far as possible** along each branch before backtracking.

Comment: a more detailed answer is here for those who still struggle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311627/intuition-behind-using-backtracking-and-not-dfs